# Items is not sorted case insensitive in combobox (SelectList)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

My task is to sort list of products items in the combobox case insensitive.

In view file:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductId, ViewData["Products"] as SelectList, 
                  @Resources.App_GlobalResources.Resource.Common_SelectItem)
```

In controller I have tried 2 implementations:

**1)**

```
var products = new SelectList(GetProducts().OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer()),
                              "id", "name", selectedProductId);
ViewData["Products"] = products;

public class CaseInsensitiveComparer : IComparer<Product>
{
  public int Compare(Product productX, Product productY)
  {
     return string.Compare(productX.Name,productY.Name,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

**2)**

```
var orderedProducts = GetProducts().OrderBy(p => p.Name.ToLower()).ToList();
var products = new SelectList(orderedProducts, "id", "name", selectedProductId)
ViewData["Products"] = products;
```

**Expected:** list sorted case insensitive
**Now:** list sorted case sensitive

But any implementation doesn't work as expected. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected, (1) how does it work and (2) what is expected?

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Are you sure you're not getting this result because of the order in which you receive the data?

Comment: Not sure in makes any difference but you can do `.OrderBy (p => p.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, so you don't need a home-made comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own helper for sorting:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DropDownListForSorted<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, 
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var model = helper.ViewData.Model;
        var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Text); // or x => x.Value
        return helper.DropDownListFor(
            expression, 
            new SelectList(orderedItems, "Value", "Text"), 
            htmlAttributes
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.DropDownListForSorted(
    x => x.SelectedItem, 
    Model.Items, 
    new { id = "mylist" }
)
```

Comment: This seems rather unnecessary? Why don't you pass a sorted list to the standard DropDownlistFor

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But you have to pass a sorted list of SelectListItem. That's why this helper is useful. I've updated the code, changing sorting from x.Value to x.Text